# Need help understanding how these assumptions imply $\| \nabla f(x) \| \leq \gamma$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lipschitz-functions

Im studying an optimization method and I am at a point where I am given these two following assumptions ($x_1$ is the starting point of the method's algorithm and f the objective function we're trying to minimize).

**1)** The level set $\mathcal{L} = \{ x: f(x) \leq f(x_1) \}$ is bounded.

**2)** In some neighborhood $\mathcal{N}$ of $\mathcal{L}$, the objective function $f$ is continuously differentiable, and it's gradient is Lipschitz continuous, i.e., there exists a constant $L>0$ such that 
$$\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(\bar x)\| \leq L\| x- \bar x\|$$
for all $x, \bar x \in \mathcal{N}$.

Now, the book proceeds to say that these assumptions imply that there is a constant $\gamma$ such that
$$ \| \nabla f(x) \| \leq \gamma, \forall x \in \mathcal{L}$$

I cant understand how this inequality is implied from these two assumptions. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

---

EDIT: My tags are probably horrible but I dont know if there are more suitable ones. Sorry in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: By definition $\mathcal{L}$ is closed. Since it is also bounded, it is a compact set. Also by the given assumptions, $\|\nabla f(x)\|$ is continuous on $\mathcal{L}$. By a theorem of Weierstrass, a continuous function defined on compact set achieves maximum and minimum. (See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) for details and generalization.) It suffices to take $\gamma$ to be the maximum.

**Remark**: One can also use the Lipschitz condition together with triangle ineqality to give a different proof: $$\| \nabla f(x)\| -\|\nabla f(x_1)\|\leq \|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(x_1)\|\leq L\|x-x_1\|$$ $$\Rightarrow \|\nabla f(x)\|\leq \|\nabla f(x_1)\|+L\|x-x_1\|\leq \|\nabla f(x_1)\|+Ld,$$ where $d$ can be taken to be $\max_{x\in\mathcal{L}}\|x-x_1\|$ by Weierstrass's theorem or any upper bound of $\|x-x_1\|$ using the given assumption that $\mathcal{L}$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you. Id really appreciate it if you could elaborate a bit more on the hint. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: No problem. Two approaches are made precise now.

Comment: You re amazing. Thanks alot :) Have a nice day